# Airflow terminates current run, and starts new run, every day at midnight, despite my CRON schedule

Tags: cron, airflow, pipeline

I have an Airflow job that I wish to run every 130 minutes.  I have set the cron schedule like this: `"*/130 * * * *".`

This schedule functions normally, until the clock hits midnight.  Each day at midnight, if a job is currently underway, Airflow will terminate the job and start a new job.  I do NOT want this behavior.  Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Cron jobs are for schedules not intervals I guess.
https://serverfault.com/questions/307481/how-to-set-cron-job-with-specific-time-interval

you can use websites like https://crontab.guru/ to verify your cron expressions